# How to install RoboBrowser for Python 3.4

Tags: python, robobrowser

Can somebody give me a step for step breakdown please? On this website, http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html, it says "at the command line: $ easy_install robobroswer", for installation steps. What does this mean?

Comment: Are you working on a Linux based system?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your command terminal and type **easy_install robobrowser** or if you have installed pip then you can also install by doing **pip install robobrowser** no need for $